# How to disable Xcode compiler extensions to ensure compliancy with C++ standards

Tags: c++, xcode10

I am new to learning C++, and I am using Xcode on a MacBook Pro, as suggested; however, the lesson calls for the disabling of the compiler extensions for the purpose of C++ compliancy and to ensure that the programs will work on any system

Between my ignorance of the technical jargon and practical understanding of compilers and IDEs I have not been able to resolve the requested step.